# .NET Framework 4.5 Security: SSRS calls assembly in C# generating error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, .net-4.5

I have a SSRS report that references a dll assembly with one class that should call a stored procedure but returns this error.

**Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, system.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**

I don't know C# but have been limping through this with the help of some friends and colleagues.  One had me add:

```
using System.Security.Permissions;
SqlClientPermission oPerm = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
oPerm.Assert();
```

to the class and I got this error:
**Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods**

Leading me to look at what changed after .NET 4.0.  I removed the SQLClientPermissions bit and added this to the AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]
[assembly: SecurityCritical()]
```

Which returned the original error.  This is the Class:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string logReportAttributes(string ReportName, int GlobalsTotalPages)
        {
            string retValue = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                long TOCExecutionID = long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=True;initial catalog=InternalApps;data source=DEVSQL1;User ID=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_LogReportAttributes", connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportName", ReportName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalsTotalPages", GlobalsTotalPages);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
                retValue = "Sent Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retValue = string.Format ( "{0} \n\r {1}" , ex.Message != null ? ex.Message : "" , ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "");
            }
             return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to get the correct security set up for this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original error is an error that comes from code policy settings for the report server.  There's a config file called RSSrvPolicy.config where you can specify different CodeGroups and their appropriate trust level (in ReportServer\bin).  There you can grant a DLL FullTrust access.

This MSDN page goes over some of the details and more importantly has an example of a CodeGroup tag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154658.aspx#Anchor_1